# Completely missing Dot Net in Windows 10 -1909?

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I recently upgraded my Windows 10 Pro 1903 desktop to 1909. I downloaded the full 1909 ISO and run Setup.exe. The process went thru fine. However a program called 'Windows ISO Downloader' started giving Error 135. To my best understanding it occurs if required .Net framework is missing.

I looked into **Programs and Features** and **Turn Windows feature On/Off** and there was no .Net framework in the list. There are 3 options called, .Net, .Net Extensibility 3.5 & 4.8 which just do not get enabled. I mean I can tick them but after Windows does something they go back to unticked state.

There are no items like .Net 2 & 3.5 & .Net 4.8 under Programs.

I tried to download any recent Windows 10 updates but it now gives error 0x80d02014 so it's altogether another issue. I do not know the state of .Net framework in 1903 as I never needed it ever in 1903, so this might have been a pre-existing issue or might have been introduced after 1909.

Trying to install offline .Net 4.7 or 4.8 says that it's already installed as part of OS.

I tried to download and run a third party utility that shows what .Net is present and it returns nothing. Below are relevant screenshots.

Let me know if you have any further pointers for troubleshooting this issue. Clean install on Windows 10 might fix the issue but that's the last options. Looks like my current Windows 10 is in a total mess.

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**

As suggested in comments I tried to use DISM to enable .Net feature but it returns Error 50. I ran CMD as admin. Unfortunately the contents of Log file are beyond my understanding.

[image]

I tried to reset Windows 10 but to my surprise it says your apps shall be removed. Similarly Repair attempt tells me that no files and apps will be kept. The option to select first 2 of the 3 options is grayed out.

[image]

I think there's something wrong with my Windows 10 1909 and I am still back to square one. I am sure clean install is going to fix it but it will be my last option.

Comment: I know you were being thorough, but the only Add Features screenshot needed is the very first one, as Add Features is always sorted alphabetically with .Net always being at the very top due to the `.`.  Also _Windows ISO Downloader_ is not apart of Windows Setup and is not a relavant application for Windows 10 (or 8) since Microsoft makes the ISO [publicly available](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).  .Net is also made available as a [standalone installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10)

Comment: If Windows is working properly, adding .NET via Windows Features will work. Try running a Windows 10 Repair install from the Media Creation Link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks. As I mentioned in my question, trying to install .Net offline returns error that it's already installed. So that option is ruled out.

Comment: My bad, I totally missed that in your question.  The component store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`) is what controls what features can and cannot be installed - if .Net was turned off for some reason, try: `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3` or `DISM /Online /Get-Features`, then replace `NetFx3` with the correct option.  Otherwise, issue the following _in the order given_: `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` > `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` > Reboot > `SFC /ScanNow` > Reboot > retry feature commands from beginning.

Comment: Enable-Feature did not work. Now trying the Cleanup-Image commands. Will update here soon. Thanks.

Comment: Ensure you run those three commands in the order they're listed, otherwise, you'll need to re-run them, as each depends on the command that precedes it: 1st: `/startcomponentcleanup`, 2nd: `/restorehealth`, 3rd: `/scannow`, then retry `/enable-feature`, updating your question with the applicable error line from the `%WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` _(also from the `%WinDir%\Logs\DISM\dism.log` if any errors populate there)_.  Only errors from the very bottom of each would be applicable - check the timestamps, best viewed in a text editor like VS Code, Atom, Notepad++, etc.

Comment: I tried the 3 commands in elevated CMD prompt in the same sequence including reboot before SFC and they did not return any errors as such. I even tried the enable-feature thereafter but still get the same error 50 and .Net 3.5 & 4.8 are not listed under Windows Features.

Comment: Unfortunately, @John's recommendation for a Repair Install is the only other option then.  I don't know where Microsoft keeps Windows 10's changelog at, but it may be worth a look before doing a Repair Install, as there may be something that Microsoft changed in regards to .Net for the v1909 bi-annual update _(or even verify with someone else who has v1909 installed if they're experiencing the same - I can verify in a few hours as I'm about to reboot so it can install)_

Comment: Try the Repair Install method for this issue. Quite easy to do.  I have V1909 running on several machines with no issues

Comment: It is not possible for .NET Framework 4.8.0 to not be installed on Windows 10 version 1909.

Comment: Where to got the 'raymondcc .net detector' please?

Comment: @ahdung  Follow this blog and see if the link is still active therein  https://whatsoftware.com/how-to-check-what-version-of-microsoft-net-framework-is-installed-in-computer/

Comment: @rajeev Thank you, but this site has a big bug, can't download everything, it just give you "download.php".

Answer (score 2):

This started occurring in my company. I thought it might be the provider we use to install our images that might be screwing it up, but it could be something with 1903.

Anyway, when you try to re-install it just says that Dot Net is already in the system but turned off. This causes any .application files to not be associated with anything, there's powershell errors, Teams has issues loading.. basically anything .net.

Put this in a .bat or .cmd file, or just run it line by line in an Admin Command prompt.:

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OC-Package /norestart
start /w pkgmgr /iu:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-US-OC-Package /norestart
start /w pkgmgr /iu:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-WCF-OC-Package /norestart
start /w pkgmgr /iu:Microsoft-Windows-NetFx4-WCF-US-OC-Package /norestart
```

Reboot after all these go through, and everything should be back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

> I recently upgraded my Windows 10 Pro 1903 desktop to 1909. I downloaded the full 1909 ISO and run Setup.exe. The process went thru fine. However a program called 'Windows ISO Downloader' started giving Error 135.

.NET Framework is built-into Windows 10 version 1903 and Windows 10 version 1909.  **It is not possible for at least this version of the .NET Framework to be installed.**

The error you have received, is likely due to the fact the application you are attempting to use, is specifically trying to target a version of the .NET Framework you don't have installed.  I suggest using official Microsoft tool to download a Windows 10 version 1909 ISO.  You can use the Media Creation Tool and/or the Upgrade Assistant.  **`Windows ISO Downloader` was only recently updated to support .NET Framework 4.8 on November 8th 2019.**  If you were not using Version 8.22, and would like to still use the tool, you need to download that version.

`RaymondCC .NET Detector` looks at registry keys that are created when you install .NET Framework.  It does not support the .NET Framework version that are included with Windows 8.0+

> I tried to download any recent Windows 10 updates but it now gives
>   error 0x80d02014 so it's altogether another issue. I do not know the
>   state of .Net framework in 1903 as I never needed it ever in 1903, so
>   this might have been a pre-existing issue or might have been
>   introduced after 1909.

The built-in version of the .NET Framework for Windows 10 version 1903 was .NET Framework 4.8

> I looked into Programs and Features and Turn Windows feature On/Off
>   and there was no .Net framework in the list. There are 3 options
>   called, .Net, .Net Extensibility 3.5 & 4.8 which just do not get
>   enabled. I mean I can tick them but after Windows does something they
>   go back to unticked state.
>
> There are no items like .Net 2 & 3.5 & .Net 4.8 under Programs.

.NET Framework 4.5+ has never been located in the list of Windows Features for any version of Windows.  The lack of .NET Framework 3.5 is likely due to your WinSxS directory not containing it.

You can install .NET Framework 3.5 if you run the same command you ran, but provide a source, to the components you need.

> Trying to install offline .Net 4.7 or 4.8 says that it's already
>   installed as part of OS.

This is due to the fact the .Net Framework 4.8 is already installed on Windows 10 version 1903 and Windows 10 version 1909.  .NET Framework 4.8 is an in-place upgrade to .NET Framework 4.5

> I tried to reset Windows 10 but to my surprise it says your apps shall
>   be removed. Similarly Repair attempt tells me that no files and apps
>   will be kept. The option to select first 2 of the 3 options is grayed
>   out.

This normally only happens when you have moved vital folders like the user's profile to a non-standard location.

> I think there's something wrong with my Windows 10 1909 and I am still
>   back to square one. I am sure clean install is going to fix it but it
>   will be my last option.

Your inability to install .NET Framework 3.5 is extremely easy to fix and likely the reason your unable to run the third-party application.  Perform the following steps to solve that problem.

1. Download a Windows 10 version 1909 ISO
2. Mount the ISO within Windows 10
3. Run the following command, the command assumes, the drive letter assigned to the virtual mount is `D`:

   - `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs`

Source: [Deploy .NET Framework 3.5 by using Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-net-framework-35-by-using-deployment-image-servicing-and-management--dism)

Answer (score 0):

This has been is issue ever since Windows 10 was introduced. The only way we have been able to enable .NET Framework 3.5.

To enable:

1. You need to ISO file or installation CD of the appropriate Windows 10 build version.
2. Mount the ISO and copy the "SXS" folder in the "Sources" folder to the local C: drive or local location.
3. Open CMD as Administrator.
4. Run dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:C:\sxs /LimitAccess.

Once you are done, check if .NET Framework 3.5 is enabled in *Windows Features*.

[image]